# How to access offsets of inner SVG elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I have some SVG files and I would place hundreds of those SVG files in HTML DOM using the  tag. The SVG files contains inner elements such as . How do I access the offsets of these inner elements? Here is the content of a sample SVG file: https://jsbin.com/tapedam/edit?html,output.

How does accessing offsets help me?

By accessing offsets I would be able to sustain the connections with other SVG objects even if they are moved anywhere in the DOM.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: @Robert Longson, I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. I want to access offsets of inner SVG elements in a DOM and not the SVG object.

Answer (score 0):

Get a DOM reference to the element you are interested in and then you can call one of the following functions:

[`getBBox()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#types-__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox)

Returns the bounding box of the element in local SVG coordinates.  Note that any transforms on the element or it's ancestors will affect the coordinate values returned.

[`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Returns the bounding box of the element in browser coordinates.  However note that these coordinates may not be able to be used directly to create a new SVG element. That's because the SVG may be at a different scale, or the element may have a transform.

If you need to convert between local SVG coordinates and screen coordinates, then there are [functions for that also](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#types-InterfaceSVGLocatable).

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm working on your suggestions. Will keep you posted. The challenge here is that the SVG file is inside an `<object>` tag and I might get a cross origin frame error. Also here is the screenshot [link] (https://ibin.co/35FOXOHj9J0U.png) of what I'm testing. As I said earlier I want the offsets of the `<line>` elements which are inside the `<svg>`

Comment: After analyzing various alternatives I realized that Instead of using <object> tag it's better to directly add the SVG elements inside the SVG canvas. This way I'll have more control and flexibility. 

I may sill have to use:  
getBBox() and getBoundingClientRect() to get the offsets. 

You may close this thread for now as resolved.